# apache pig - store files based on date column

Tags: apache-pig

Please help me.. I have scenario below - input file..

```
ID name Time-stamp 
1234 kiran 18-MAR-2015 01:02:31
1234 kiran 18-MAR-2015 01:02:31
1234 kiran 19-MAR-2015 01:02:31 
1234 kiran 18-MAR-2015 11:02:31 
1234 kiran 20-MAR-2015 01:02:00
1234 kiran 11-MAR-2015 21:12:31
1234 kiran 18-MAR-2015 01:02:31 
1234 kiran 30-MAR-2015 01:02:31
1234 kiran 22-MAR-2015 01:11:00
1234 kiran 30-MAR-2015 01:02:31
1234 kiran 19-MAR-2015 01:02:00
```

now i need to write output files based on the dates in Time-stamp column output would be:

```
user/username/DATE/part-m-000000
```

-- DATE is variable so folder name should be

```
user/username/18-MAR-2015/part-m-000000
```

above file contains all the value on single date

```
1234 kiran 18-MAR-2015 01:02:31
1234 kiran 18-MAR-2015 01:02:31 
1234 kiran 18-MAR-2015 11:02:31 
1234 kiran 18-MAR-2015 01:02:31
```

another folder name should be

```
user/username/19-MAR-2015/part-m-000000
```

above file contains all the value on single date

```
1234 kiran 19-MAR-2015 01:02:31 
1234 kiran 19-MAR-2015 01:02:00
```

another folder name should be

```
user/username/20-MAR-2015/part-m-000000
```

above file contains all the value on singe date

```
1234 kiran 20-MAR-2015 01:02:00
```

another folder name should be

```
user/username/22-MAR-2015/part-m-000000
```

above file contains all the value on singe date

1234 kiran 22-MAR-2015 01:11:00

another folder name should be

```
user/username/30-MAR-2015/part-m-000000
```

above file contains all the value on singe date

```
1234 kiran 30-MAR-2015 01:02:31
1234 kiran 30-MAR-2015 01:02:31
```

Please help me

Thank you.. Sree

Answer (score 0):

Below steps should help -

1. Use Date Functions to convert the time-stamp to the required format.
2. Group by date
3. flatten the group
4. Save the result of #3 using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage.